# mysql: updating record gives "Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value" error

Tags: php, mysql

Not sure why it's happening:

```
mysql_query("update items set photoids=photoids+',$newphotoid' where id='$row[id]'");
```

photoids cell is initially empty, but command is going through the cycle to populate with photoids red through scandir().

$newphotoid for sure exists and always unique as well as $row[id].

Completely lost. Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is the field type of the `photoids` field? Right now it appears you're trying to assign a STRING to that field, by adding multiple comma-separated values to it. If it's a float/double field, then this "string" value will be truncated/invalid.

e.g if the photoids is a float and contains "3.14159265", then you're trying to do

```
photoids = photoids + ',1234567'
photoids = 3.14159265 + ',1234567'
photoids = 3.14159265 + 0
```

resulting in:

```
photoids = 3.14159265
```

Comment: try doing `photoids = CONCAT(photoids, ',', $newphotoid)` instead, then. MySQL doesn't use `+` for concatenation.